# Sign here tabs are just working for one signer

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having a problem with the API. I have multiple signers and each signer has its own sign tab but just the first signer is able to sign without placing manually a sign tab.
I'm using a modified version of the example code of Docusign. Has anyone an idea what could be wrong?

This is the code:

```
<?php
    
    # PHP Quick start example: Send signing request by email.
    # Copyright (c) 2018 by DocuSign, Inc.
    # License: The MIT License -- https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
    
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    require_once('vendor/docusign/esign-client/autoload.php');
    
    function send_document_for_signing(){
        #
        # The document $fileNamePath will be sent to be signed by <signer_name>
    
        # Settings
        # Fill in these constants
        #
        # Obtain an OAuth access token from https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator
        $accessToken = '**ACCESS TOKEN**';
        # Obtain your accountId from demo.docusign.com -- the account id is shown in the drop down on the
        # upper right corner of the screen by your picture or the default picture. 
        $accountId = '**ACCOUNT ID**';
        # Recipient Information:
        # The document you wish to send. Path is relative to the root directory of this repo.
        $fileNamePath = 'demo_documents/World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf';
    
        # The API base_path
        $basePath = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi';
    
        # Constants
        $appPath = getcwd();
    
        #
        # Step 1. The envelope definition is created.
        #         One signHere tab is added.
        #         The document path supplied is relative to the working directory
        #
        # Create the component objects for the envelope definition...
        $contentBytes = file_get_contents($appPath . "/" . $fileNamePath);
        $base64FileContent =  base64_encode ($contentBytes);
    
        # create the DocuSign document object
        $document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  
            'document_base64' => $base64FileContent, 
            'name' => 'Example document', # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'pdf', # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => '1' # a label used to reference the doc
        ]);
        
        # The signer object
        $signer = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([ 
            'email' => '**mail1**', 'name' => '**name1**', 'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1",
        ]);
    
        $signer2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
            'email' => '**mail2**', 'name' => '**name2**', 'recipient_id' => "2", 'routing_order' => "2",
        ]);
    
        # DocuSign SignHere field/tab object
        $signHere = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ 
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '1', 
            'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '195', 'y_position' => '147'
        ]);
    
        $signHere2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '2',
            'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '230', 'y_position' => '180'
        ]);
    
        # Add the tabs to the signer object
        # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        $signer->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere2, $signHere]]));
    
        # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
        $envelopeDefinition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
            'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
            'documents' => [$document], # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
            # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
            'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer, $signer2]]),
            'status' => "sent" # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
        ]);
        
        #
        #  Step 2. Create/send the envelope.
        #
        $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
        $config->setHost($basePath);
        $config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " . $accessToken);
        $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
        $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $results = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelopeDefinition);
        return $results;
    };
    
    # Mainline
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        try {
            $results = send_document_for_signing();
            ?>
    <html lang="en">
        <body>
        <h4>Results</h4>
        <p>Status: <?= $results['status'] ?>, Envelope ID: <?= $results['envelope_id'] ?></p>
        </body>
    </html>
            <?php
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            if ($e instanceof DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException) {
                print ("\nDocuSign API error information: \n");
                var_dump ($e->getResponseBody());
            }
        }    
        die();
    }
    # Since it isn't a POST, print the form:
    ?>
    <html lang="en">
        <body>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Send document signature request!"
                    style="width:21em;height:2em;background:#1f32bb;color:white;font:bold 1.5em arial;margin: 3em;"/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcA6M.png)

(That's the view of the first signer. Instead of just one sign tab are there two, which needed to be sign by the first signer.)

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding tabs (signing elements) for one of the two signers in this line:

```
 $signer->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere2, $signHere]]));
```

You can add a line like this but should probably think what tabs you need for the second signer:

```
 $signer2->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere2, $signHere]]));
```